# Преобразовать массив в объект

Tags: javascript

> *Как преобразовать массив вида*

```
[
 "drawMarker:  false",
 "drawMarker1: false",
 "drawMarker2: false",
 "drawMarker3: false",
 "drawMarker4: false",
 "drawMarker5: false",
 "drawMarker6: false"
]
```

> *В обьект*

```
 {
  drawMarker:  false,
  drawMarker1: false,
  drawMarker2: false,     
  drawMarker3: false,   
  drawMarker4: false,    
  drawMarker5: false,      
  drawMarker6: false      

  };
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
var a = [
  "drawMarker:  false",
  "drawMarker1: false",
  "drawMarker2: false",
  "drawMarker3: false",
  "drawMarker4: false",
  "drawMarker5: false",
  "drawMarker6: false"
];
var b = a.reduce((acc, item) => {
  var p = item.split(":");
  acc[p[0]] = JSON.parse(p[1].trim());
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(b);
```

Comment: ок, Игорь -- шикарно))

Comment: @МаксимКрылов Очень хорошо. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: @igor челы вообще галочки не ставят:( на тебе плюсик :)